# Risk in returning HTML content on AJAX call via HTTPS

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, security

I wanted to load HTML contents dynamically, such as updating a Bootstrap's modal dialog contents via AJAX call (because refreshing the page and showing the modal again is weird), but before I do that, I want to know **what risks** that I will need to concern when doing so, and possible solutions.

The main reason to do this is that I'm developing a portlet for Liferay, and I wished to update the content of my portlet dynamically without refreshing the whole page.

Of course I could return data in JSON from my server to client, but I will have to write complex client side logic to update the DOM, which the logic is probably done easier in, say, JSP

Assume the webapp is HTTPS only, not sure if this will help with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that the webapp is HTTPS only, it would be very good to let all AJAX calls also use that. This will not create a breach of mixing unsecure and secure connections, and the warning dialogs, which browsers give.

The only risk can be caused by cross-site scripting, if parts of the HTML is generated elsewhere or if parts of it is based on unvalidated user input.

Solutions for that is to always validate ans sanitize the input from other sources. More information about this can be found here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you chosen the wrong framework for the job and would have consider something like an client side rendering where you would bind json data to the view (eg: angular, ember, backbone or knockout)

Consider using `Element.innerText` or `$(Elm).text()` instead of `Element.innerHTML` or `$(elm).html()` when possible

Perhaps it will be a good idea to encode everything that a user can change before you save it to the database or when you are rendering the view

However if you do allow some html you would need a sanitize plugin with a witelist approtch to strict the allowed tag & attributes

the only diffrence with http and https is that it will be much harder for a [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) to read/intercept/change the content of the request & the response